# how to check wether the column in table exists or not in php

Tags: php

how to check wether the column in table exists or not in php

Comment: column and table in a database? If so which database? Or column and table on a table element in an HTML page? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the columns of the table and just check if the column you're looking for is available in the result of that.

You can execute mysql_query() to issue an SQL SHOW COLUMNS FROM table [LIKE 'name']. This will give you all columns including specifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
    print "Error";
}
```

Essentially, if the column doesn't exist, a result won't be brought up and and the variable won't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Concretely it depends on your database.

For example with Oracle databases you can query `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` or `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.

There exists however abstract solutions that let you to be not tight to a specific implementation. Zend comes to my mind but there certainly exist others. For example with Zend you can do:

`$cols = $table->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS);`

Here is the manual for Zend table: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html